# Duplicates being removed from PostgreSQL array when doing int[] - int[] but not int[] - integer

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I've been playing around with PostgreSQL's intarray module and I've noticed some seemingly odd behavior with intarrays that have duplicate elements in them. The intarray module defines two subtraction operators with pretty much the same description:

> integer[] - integer → integer[]
> Removes entries matching the right argument from the array.
>
> integer[] - integer[] → integer[]
> Removes elements of the right array from the left array.

To me, the wording above seems to ***imply*** that `A[] - B[]` is equivalent to `FOR int i IN B[]: A[] -= i`

Removing a single integer works as you'd expect, preserving duplicates:

```
SELECT '{3,1,1,2,2,2}'::int[] - 1 -->  {3,2,2,2}   (As expected)
```

Whereas removing an array removes ***all*** duplicates regardless:

```
SELECT '{3,1,1,2,2,2}'::int[] - '{1}'::int[] -->  {2,3}   (Where's my extra twos???)
```

As of PG16, the [intarray documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/intarray.html) doesn't seem to mention anything about the automatic removal of ***ALL*** duplicated entries when computing the difference between two integer arrays (suggesting that it uses set operations under the hood - which is fine, but shouldn't it say that?). So...

***Is this the intended behavior when you subtract one integer array from another in PostgreSQL?***

<sub>*For what I was doing, there was useful information stored in the number of duplicated elements in each array. While I was able to find a workaround for my application, it was still a surprise and took me a few minutes to figure out what was happening...</sub>

If it helps, I am running PostgreSQL 16.2 on Debian 12 (Specifically the official PostgreSQL Docker build of: *PostgreSQL 16.2 (Debian 16.2-1.pgdg120+2) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit*)

[image: psql result for above select statement]

[DBFiddle for above example](https://dbfiddle.uk/i-eXKhFR)

***EDIT;*** It seems this is the (set operation) behavior is correct and the PostgreSQL team have proposed an [update to the documentation](https://postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/2688665#171075007381.7104.7931589808177869854@wrigleys.postgresql.org)

Comment: Good point. You might want to fill the form at the bottom of the documentation page to suggest the correction. As to whether this was intended or not, maybe there are comments in the source code that could indicate it. My expectation would also be that it should not sort and deduplicate as a silent bonus effect of either subtraction, especially since additions do not have that effect.

Comment: It is there in 9.3-16.0: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/T93SoZzT)

Comment: I've sent the Postgres team a message, if I get a response, I'll add it to the post

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I've just tested that on `PostgreSQL 16.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1937, 64-bit` with `intarray` version 1.5 and I'm still getting `{2,3}`.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Can I ask what you get if you `\do+ - int[] int[]` in psql? It seems like you had some other extension installed or defined a custom operator, both of which might be useful to OP here. Without `create extension intarray` on a clean 16.1 I don't have that operator at all, and the extension seems to ship only with `intset_subtract` for `int[] - int[]` that adds the quiet sort+uniq.

Comment: Actually, the `set` in the name of the `int[] - int[]` operator `intset_subtract` hints that this behaviour is in fact intended. The `+` is called `intarray_push_array`, which explains why it *doesn't* turn the *array* it into a *set*.

Comment: @Zegarek My fault. I do have a `anyarray - anyarray` operator, defined a long time ago and long forgotten. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the intended behavior. At least, it has been like that since the introduction of the intarray extension. But I agree that some additional documentation wouldn't harm.

Answer (score 0):

In case that you often need a 'plain behaviour' array subtraction operator then you may define a custom one:

```sql
create or replace function array_diff(anyarray, anyarray)
returns anyarray language sql immutable as
$$
  select array_agg(item order by ordinality)
  from unnest($1) with ordinality item
  where not item = any($2);
$$;

create operator #- 
(
 function = array_diff,
 leftarg = anyarray,
 rightarg = anyarray
);
```

Comment: This explains the confusion in the comments on the question, but it doesn't appear to answer the actual question

Comment: @Bergi Yes, this was my intent - to try explain the confusion.

Comment: I think the last comment was sufficient for that. You could also delete all the other comments. Either way, this should not be posted as an answer.

Comment: I think it’s salvageable if edited to clearly propose defining one’s own custom operator that doesn’t do the surprise sort+uniq, assuming OP isn’t already doing exactly that as the workaround they mentioned (*I was able to find a workaround for my application*) and that they are interested in [solving X while asking about Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).